# Retrieve data out of a database to auto fill another form linked to the same database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Would like to know how can we retrieve data out of a html form which is saving fields in the database and auto input that data into another form linked to the database in order to save time which would be required to feed in the same details which was present in the first form.

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname="sample";

 // Create connection
 $conn =  mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
 $pos=$_REQUEST['Position'];
 $date=$_REQUEST['JoinDate'];
 $name=$_REQUEST['FirstName'];
 $lname=$_REQUEST['LastName'];
 $PhNo=$_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'];
 $email=$_REQUEST['EmailId'];
 $dob=$_REQUEST['DateofBirth'];
 $pob=$_REQUEST['PlaceOfBirth'];
 $nationality=$_REQUEST['Nationality'];
 $status=$_REQUEST['MaritalStatus'];
 $address=$_REQUEST['Address'];

 $insert_query="insert into sample.user_details   (Position,JoinDate,FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,EmailId,DateofBirth,PlaceOfBirth,Nationality,MaritalStatus,Address) values ('$pos','$date','$name','$lname','$PhNo','$email','$dob','$pob','$nationality','$status','$address')";




if($conn->query($insert_query)===TRUE) {

echo"yes";
}else{
echo "no";
}


?>
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: If you want to be help please provide your code and the code you tried so far.

Comment: Alright ill attach it .

Comment: This is the php part of it , i want to know how would i be able to retrieve these fields and use it to auto fill the same variables in another form linked to the same database but different table

Answer (score 0):

Since you've inserted the first form's data into your database, you can query your db based on the wanted condition, load your results in local variables, then put them as in value fields, so you can see them in your form. It's how info edit forms work.

Alternatively, you can save your first form's data in session variables, and use them. It is not recommended however because... you know, sessions closing and such

Comment: sql queries to select an element out of the table ?

Comment: Yes. Assume you want to retrieve data for the user whose id is 10.

`SELECT needed columns FROM table_name WHERE user_id=10;`

It is best to query according to a unique attribute.

Comment: Sorry i'm not so good at this so could you like explain how to go about the entire thing . Once i select from the first table how am i to insert that same info in the other table using query

Comment: It should look a bit like this:

`$quer="SELECT needed_columns from tablename WHERE user_id=10;"`
`$res=mysqli_query($quer);`
`if($res->num_rows>0){`
`//Save the vars in session variables (or local depending where the script is`

In the form, you will for example use in textfields:

`<input type='text' value=<?php if isset($var_name) echo $var_name;?>/>;`

After you process the data, you can then insert in your table

`$ins="Your insert query"`
`$resins=mysqli_query($ins);`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you should fetch the same data from database via id. If you are using and then using that id you can fetch all the details. Once, you have fetched all the details, then you can go ahead and write them in your html like this:

```
<input type = "text" class="form-control" value = "echo the value in here" />
```

So, this will show up your data in the form you want.

Comment: So for example the name field in the first form is being stored in the user details table , now i got another table evaluation which has the same field name which i want to get auto filled . So in the second form i should add the value of the name of the first form?

Comment: In the second form, you will fetch the data from the database which is already filled. Next, to show that data you will go ahead and echo the variable containing data in value as I mentioned above. Also, name and value are two different things. We use name to get the value from the form, but we use value to show the detail coming from database.